# What is recommended way to automate Flink Job submission on AWS EMR cluster while pipeline deployment

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr, pyflink

I am new to Flink and EMR cluster deployment. Currently we have a Flink job and we are manually deploying it on AWS EMR cluster via Flink CLI stop/start-job commands.

I wanted to automate this process (Automate updating flink job jar on every deployment happening via pipelines with savepoints) and need some recommendations on possible approaches that could be explored.

Comment: You could do something like AWS Kinesis Data Analytics already provides (updating a job from new jar on S3):  
1. build new jar and push it to S3  
2. have a script on EMR to fetch jar from S3 and run it  
3. run this script with EMR step (command-runner.jar)

Answer (score 0):

We got an option to automate this process via Flink Rest API support for all flink job operation

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/rest_api/

Sample project which used the same approach : https://github.com/ing-bank/flink-deployer